# Java Hibernate + spring-data: Cascading Childs not working when Parent is persistent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Parent-Child relashionship and my issue starts when I try to add a new Child through an update on the Parent.

When my Parent is transient, everything works fine

```
    CreditCard cc = new CreditCard("1234");

    //User
    User u1 = new User("KILLER");
    u1.addCreditCard(cc); // bi-directional happens here inside.

    // An autowired Spring Data repository that implements CrudRepository
    userRepository.save(u1);

    Assert.assertEquals(1, u1.getCreditCardCollection().size());
    Assert.assertNotNull
    (
            u1.getCreditCardCollection()
            .stream()
            .findFirst()
            .get()
            .getIdCreditCard()
    );
```

The test above is succesfully performed and an ID is generated for cc object.

But when I do:

```
    User u2 = new User("Foo Bar McLoud"); // u2 is transient

    userRepository.save(u2); // Now u2 is persistent

    u2 = userRepository.findOne(u2.getIdLogin());// just to be sure I´m working with a persistent object ;)

    CreditCard ccNew = new CreditCard("77777");

    u2.addCreditCard(ccNew );// bidirectional happens here inside

    userRepository.save(u2); // should insert a new credit card right???

    Assert.assertEquals("User should have 1 credit card.",
            1, u2.getCreditCardCollection().size()); // PASS

    Set<CreditCard> ccs = u2.getCreditCardCollection();
    for (CreditCard cc : ccs) {
        Assert.assertNotNull("CreditCard ID is null", cc.getIdCreditCard()); // FAIL: id is not generated. The database entry was not set. Added credit card is still transient... 
    }
```

So, in my second Test, my ccNew is still transient after an update on its parent.

Why is it still transient??

Child configuration:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "id_user")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private User user;
```

Parent configuration:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<CreditCard> creditCardCollection = new HashSet<>();
```

Already tried on Parent:

```
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user",cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<CreditCard> creditCardCollection = new HashSet<>();
```

Comment: What are you using for `userRepository.save` method ? Are you using `getEntityManager().merge(value)` or `getEntityManager().persist(value)` ?

Comment: None.. just using spring-jpa... Just decrlared an annotated interface UserRepository and autowired it in a class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you test work inside one transaction ,in this you work with (u2.getCreditCardCollection()) with values from object not with entity (save is not executed yet):

> Assert.assertEquals("User should have 2 credit cards.",
>                   1, u2.getCreditCardCollection().size());

when you iterate over u2.getCreditCardCollection() and check id , they are null as insert and id generation comes only in commit stage or flush/clear context.

You need call saveAndFlush() instead of just save().

```
    u2 = userRepository.findOne(u2.getIdLogin());

    CreditCard ccNew = new CreditCard("77777");

    u2.addCreditCard(ccNew );// bidirectional happens here inside

    userRepository.saveAndFlush(u2); 

    Assert.assertEquals("User should have 2 credit cards.",
            1, u2.getCreditCardCollection().size()); // PASS

    Set<CreditCard> ccs = u2.getCreditCardCollection();
    for (CreditCard cc : ccs) {
        Assert.assertNotNull("CreditCard ID is null", cc.getIdCreditCard());
    }
```

from api ;

> void flush() Flushes all pending changes to the database.
>
> S saveAndFlush(S entity)
>   Saves an entity and flushes changes instantly

Comment: Amazing. I´ve been using "... UserRepository extends CrudRepository...". CrudRepository does not have saveAndFlush, so I thought CrudRepository could perform auto-flush.. or something like.

I changed CrudRepository to JpaRepository and everithing works fine.

Errata: where you read "Assert.assertEquals("User should have 2 credit cards..." now read "Assert.assertEquals("User should have 1 credit card".

Thank you very much